# Ajax request with prototype - what is transport if not only responseText?

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

This is an example code from the prototype site.

```
var url = '/proxy?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.google.com/search?q=Prototype');
// notice the use of a proxy to circumvent the Same Origin Policy.

new Ajax.Request(url, {
  method: 'get',
  onSuccess: function(transport) {
    var notice = $('notice');
    if (transport.responseText.match(/href="http:\/\/prototypejs.org/))
      notice.update('Yeah! You are in the Top 10!').setStyle({ background: '#dfd' });
    else
      notice.update('Damn! You are beyond #10...').setStyle({ background: '#fdd' });
  }
});
```

The data that comes from the ajax request is available at transport.responseText, but what is transport if not only responseText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's a [Ajax.Response](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/response) object.  The linked page lists all the other properties.  It's a wrapper around the actual XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: You're right, it's a simple wrapper with slightly friendlier method names like getHeader instead of getResponseHeader.

Comment: It's not just friendlier names. It adds the JSON stuff, and has different behavior when there are no headers.